# Uploadify - change destination folder to another folder on different hardive

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, uploadify

I am new to uploadify. I recently installed on a xamp in my local `c:/` where uploadify resides. I have an uploads folder in the httdocs of xampp where all my uploads go. However I would like to move my uploads to a folder on a different drive. I've tried to edit the `uploadifive.php` but to no avail. I would like to move from `'/uploads'(C:\xampp\htdocs\uploadify)` to uploads in `(L:\ibi\apps\ibisamp\uploads)`. I am using the html-5 version.

Here is my code:

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Elavon MDM</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.uploadifive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadifive.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
 font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
.uploadifive-button {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#queue {
 border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
 height: 177px;
 overflow: auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0 3px 3px;
 width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- <h1>Data Management Upload Demo</h1> -->
 <form>
  <div id="queue"></div>
  <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="false">
  <a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  <?php $timestamp = time();?>
  $(function() {
   $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'auto'             : false,
    'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
    // 'fileTypeExts'     : '*.csv',
    'formData'         : {
            'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                         },
    'queueID'          : 'queue',
    'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
    'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**uploadifive.php**

```html
<?php
/*
UploadiFive
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
*/

// Set the upload directory
$uploadDir = '/uploads/';

// Set the allowed file extensions
$fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'csv', 'png'); // Allowed file extensions

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
 $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
 $uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
 $targetFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

 // Validate the filetype
 $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
 if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']), $fileTypes)) {

  // Save the file
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
  echo 1;

 } else {

  // The file type wasn't allowed
  echo 'Invalid file type.';

 }
}
?>
```

**checkexists.php**

```html
<?php
/*
UploadiFive
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
*/

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root and should match the upload folder in the uploader script

if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) {
 echo 1;
} else {
 echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: In uploadifive.php change the value of the `$uploadDir` to L:\ibi\apps\ibisamp\uploads (`$uploadDir = 'L:\ibi\apps\ibisamp\uploads\'`

Comment: Thanks @dave I tried that, however nothing uploads in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
$uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
```

with

```
$uploadDir  = "L:\ibi\apps\ibisamp\" . $uploadDir;
```

Comment: Am I adding both lines of code to uploadifive.php? What about checkexists.php?

Comment: IT WORKED THANKS! just had to use L:/ibi/apps/ibisamp/

Comment: Can you help me with the checkexists.php?

Comment: yeah sure, do the same replace `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with `"L:\ibi\apps\ibisamp\"`